# Merging rows within a group together in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with linking rows using pandas. I have the following table:

| Product | Country | Price1 | Price2 | Price3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | USA | 10 | - | 30 |
| P2 | France | 9 | - | - |
| P3 | Germany | 11 | - | - |
| P1 | USA | - | 20 | - |
| P3 | Germany | - | - | 35 |

I would like to combine the rows grouping by `product` and `country` so as to merge them into one row.

| Product | Country | Price1 | Price2 | Price3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | USA | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| P2 | France | 9 | - | - |
| P3 | Germany | 11 | - | 35 |

I think there is a risk of overwriting cells here if the same fields have different values so I'm wondering how best to do this.

| Product | Country | Price1 | Price2 | Price3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | USA | `10` | - | 30 |
| P2 | France | 9 | - | - |
| P3 | Germany | 11 | - | - |
| P1 | USA | `12` | 20 | - |
| P3 | Germany | - | - | 35 |

I'm wondering how best to do this.

Comment: So, what should be the output if you have the latest case? Assuming `-` are NaNs and the numbers are numeric type, you can get the sum with `df.groupby(['Product', 'Country'], as_index=False).sum()`

Comment: ok there is no problem with numbers, but what if they are strings? for example not 10 but ''ten"?

Comment: You can use `df.groupby(['Product', 'Country'], as_index=False).first()` if you want the first occurrence.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well, as I said, what would you want if you had "ten"? I cannot decide the aggregation logic for you. There are dozen of possibilities, do you want to concatenate the strings? Get the first? The longest? The first one in lexicographic order?